# Debug---Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault

Tags: c++, sorting

The code is here, and it is compiled by G++. After input N=600000 and enter. A window popped out said that ***.exe has stopped working**. When debugging the code, a window titled **Error** said that **Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.** when come to sort line. Now, I know it's stackoverflow error.Thank you, all guys!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>     /* srand, rand */
#include <algorithm>

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {

int N;
std::cout << "N:";
int a[N];
for(int i = 0; i < N; i++){
    a[i] = rand()%N;
}
std::sort(a,a+N);
std::cout << "The "<<N/2<<"th smallest number is: " << a[N/2-1] <<"\n";
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please elaborate on "error occured when running it".

Comment: 600,000 ints on the stack? Time to look at the name of this site.

Comment: @chris When running the code, a window popped out said that ***.exe has stopped working**. When debugging the code, a window titled **Error** said that **Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.** when come to sort.        Now, I know it's stackoverflow. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

600000 array size is too much memory on stack.Instead use a global array.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>     /* srand, rand */
#include <algorithm>
const int MAX = 600001;
int a[MAX]; //make it global
    int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
}
```

Comment: That defeats the purpose of inputting the number of elements at runtime.

Comment: This could be helpful if there is restriction on using STL.

Comment: ...like not being allowed to use `std::sort()`, which came from the STL initially?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, an array with a run-time size is a C99 feature and only provided as extension in some C++ compilers. Switch this to a `std::vector<int> a(N);` and the code should work.

BTW:

- Sorting this is not the fastest way to find the N-th smallest number.
- Please consider Chris' comment, that your question lacks the necessary information. Also, indent and clean up your code, I don't think that it's necessary to run a loop.
- You can also retrieve input from IOStreams, no need to use `scanf()`: `while (cin >> N) { /*use n*/ }`.

Comment: To expand on your first point, `std::nth_element` does this in linear time.

Comment: True, but I didn't want to do other people's homework, @chris. :)

Comment: Eh, if there's one thing I've learned, it's that if the OP has homework to find the nth smallest number, a single call to a library function will be disallowed. Considering `std::sort` is being used (with the same effect, but less efficiently), I doubt it's homework honestly. If that wasn't meant to be literal "homework", I'm sorry.